# Getting Facebook's react.js library JSX syntax to play nicely with jslint?

Tags: javascript, facebook, jslint, jshint, reactjs

I am playing around with the Facebook's [react.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) library. I am trying to use their JSX syntax which describes creating a view in the following way.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{'Hello ' + this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

JSLint obviously does not like this ("expected an identifier and instead saw ' <';" - JavaScript syntax error), so how do I get around this in my .jshintrc file?

Comment: You don't. It's not valid JavaScript, so understandably JS static analysis tools can't cope with it. You would have to modify JSLint/JSHint to add this functionality.

Comment: Ya you are right. Guys maintaining the repo might create a fork of jshint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(**Update:** This post is from 2013 and obsolete now.)

I use JSHint + JSX.

It shouldn't require a fork of JSHint, there should be a way to tell JSHint to disable all warnings for a block of code. Unfortunately there is no such way to disable *all* warnings, only a specific set of warnings, so I may end up submitting a pull request to add this, or change linters.

**Update:** [We submitted a pull request which was accepted](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1260). To disable all warnings, add `/*jshint ignore: start */` to start the section, and `/*jshint ignore: end */` to end it.

As you noted, the workflow Facebook and Instagram use is to lint outside the IDE from the command line.

Your other option is to extract all your JSX templates into their own files, and make them a function of scope instead of existing inside an implicit lexical scope. We tried it out and didn't like the amount of boilerplate.

(**Note:** I am not affiliated with the React team.)

Comment: Been working on this specifically.  The recommendation from the IRC channel is to lint the output from the jsx "transpiler". I've actually been working on a node module that wraps jshint that will transform any jsx files it find.

Comment: The pull request is merged, by the way, at least as of JSHint 2.4. However, I highly recommend using granular options instead of `ignore:start`: [see rationale](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21707007/458193).

Answer (score 30):

I tried to follow [Dustin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799388/458193) and [STRML's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20766000/458193) advice on this thread, and here's what worked best for me.

### Development Setup

I use Sublime Text with [SublimeLinter](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) + [SublimeLinter-jshint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint) + [SublimeLinter-jsxhint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jsxhint).
These are very nice plugins that let me see mistakes when I save the file, *both* for JS and JSX files:

[image]

These plugins respect your project's `.jshintrc` and I can't recommend them enough.

Make sure to follow installation instructions for all three packages, or they won't work:

- Installing **SublimeLinter** is straightforward (**[instructions](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-via-pc)**);
- **SublimeLinter-jshint** needs a global `jshint` in your system (**[instructions](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint#linter-installation)**);
- **SublimeLinter-jsxhint** needs a global [`jsxhint`](https://github.com/STRML/SublimeLinter-jsxhint) in your system, as well as [JavaScript (JSX) bundle](https://raw.github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jsxhint/master/JavaScript%20(JSX).tmLanguage) inside `Packages/JavaScript` (**[instructions](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jsxhint#linter-installation)**).

You can configure the linter to execute every few seconds, on file save, or manually.

### Build Step, Commit Hook, etc

We're using JSHint as part of our Git workflow and as a build step to enforce the guidelines. We could have used [jsxhint](https://github.com/STRML/JSXHint/) but we wanted to keep using [grunt-contrib-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) so this wasn't an option.

Right now, we're running normal `jshint` as a build step **after** `react` transformation, so it just processes the output JS files.

It would be cool if somebody forked [grunt-contrib-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) and made a version that works with `jsxhint`, but it doesn't look like an easy task to me. (Update: somebody [did just that](https://github.com/tillarnold/grunt-jsxhint) but I haven't tested it.)

### Ignoring Violations in Generated Code

JSX compiler generates code that breaks a few our conventions.

I didn't want to use `ignore:start` and `ignore:end` [as suggested by Dustin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799388/458193) since this would effectively disable *all* linting inside `render` methods. It is a bad idea in my book. For example, excluding `render` method from linting makes linter think I don't use some of the libraries and child components that I declare with `require` at the top of the file. **Therefore, the need to ignore things spreads from `render` method to the rest of the file, and this defeats the purpose of `ignore:start` completely.**

Instead, I explicitly decorate each `render` method with three JSHint options that JSX compiler (currently) breaks for me:

```
render: function () {
  /* jshint trailing:false, quotmark:false, newcap:false */
}
```

This is sufficient in my case; for your `.jshintrc` this may need some tuning.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but I am having trouble getting Sublime to use the correct linter for the .jsx-files. It is always using jshint instead of jsxhint. How did you get around this problem?

Comment: @NilsMagneLunde Does it show JSX syntax is being used in lower right corner? Did you restart Sublime?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Changing it to jsx seems to have solved the problems :-) Now I just need to figure out how to make Sublime recognize the jsx-files automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @NilsMagneLunde Maybe you need to “Open all with current extension as”? See http://i.imgur.com/3thgqp6.png

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic answer. This one assumes that sublime is the used IDE. :(

Answer (score 14):

JsxHint and JSHint arent the best tools for linting JSX. JSHint does not support JSX and all JsxHint does is transforms JSX and then runs JSHint on the transformed code. 
I have been using (and would highly recommend) [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) with the [React plugin](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react). This is better since Eslint can parse any Javascript flavor using custom parsers like [esprima-fb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima-fb) or [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) (see update below).

Sample `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
    "parser": "esprima-fb",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },

    "rules": {
        "no-mixed-requires": [0, false],
        "quotes": [2, "single"],
        "strict": [1, "never"],
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "curly": 1,
        "no-bitwise": 1,
        "max-len": [1, 110, 4],
        "vars-on-top": 0,
        "guard-for-in": 1,
        "react/display-name": 1,
        "react/jsx-quotes": [2, "double", "avoid-escape"],
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
        "react/prop-types": 2,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/wrap-multilines": 2
    },

    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },

    "plugins": [ "react" ],

    "globals": {
        "d3": true,
        "require": "true",
        "module": "true",
        "$": "true",
        "d3": "true"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

esprima-fb will soon be deprecated by Facebook. Use [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) as a parser for eslint. A good place to know more about how you can setup Babel & Eslint to work with React is [this Github project](https://github.com/ameyms/react-seed).

Comment: Agree. Check this for more info: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/lint-like-it-s-2015-6987d44c5b48

Comment: As the author of JSXHint... I wholeheartedly agree. JSXHint is a hack I put together in a weekend so I could just get some basic linting working without terrible `ignore` hacks. ESLint actually parses the code correctly and has support for a lot more ES6/ES7 features to boot. It's a better project and I have switched to it in my own work as well.

Answer (score 5):

See [JSXHint](https://github.com/STRML/JSXHint), a wrapper around JSHint I wrote that lints the output from `react-tools`. This is a step up from ignoring a block of lines as it will actually lint the generated javascript.

It can be used with Sublime Text via SublimeLinter with [this plugin](https://github.com/STRML/SublimeLinter-jsxhint).

Comment: There is also online version: www.jsxhint.com

Answer (score 2):

Guys maintaining the repo are incredibly helpful. You just have to run it threw the JSX transform to produce valid javascript unless someone creates a fork of jshint. If there is enough interest, it might be put on the roadmap for future release of the react framework. Can look at the coversation thread [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/121#issuecomment-19888524).

Comment: I recently put in a [pull request](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1260) to jshint that adds a feature to ignore a block of lines in javascript and resume linting afterward. I specifically had JSX in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I use grunt + react-tools + jshint to lint the .js files built using react-tools. The output from react-tools is very good about keeping your spacing, indentation, etc, when converting your .jsx to .js, so it gives you an accurate file to lint against.

To setup, install grunt [the normal way](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started). Then install the grunt-contrib-watch, react-tools, grunt-react, and grunt-contrib-jshint.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch react-tools grunt-react grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
```

here is a sample grunt file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Task configuration
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: true,
            },
            react: {
                src: ['react/**/*.js']
            }
        },
        react: {
            files: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'react/',
                src: ['**/*.jsx'],
                dest: 'react/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            jsx: {
                files: ['react/**/*.jsx'],
                tasks: ['react', 'jshint:react']
            }
        }
    });

    // These plugins provide necessary tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-react');

    // Default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['react', 'jshint:react']);
};
```

In this file, running "grunt" will compile your .jsx to .js and then lint the .js files. You can run "grunt watch" to run after every save.

Most of my usual .jshintrc settings work when running this way. I ran into a few issues initially, but most were resolved by making changes in your .jsx files. For exapmle, I have "newcap" set to true. When I followed the [React tutorial's](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) naming convention and capitalized the first letter of tags, this threw a lint error. It was fixed by lower-casing the first letter of tags.

I did have to set "trailing": false in my .jshintrc. The resulting .js files have trailing whitespaces where it converts tags to Javascript. I haven't figured out if there is a react-tools configuration to change this. You can use the method described in Dan's post if you don't want to change your .jshintrc.

In addition to linting, this process also helps catch issues with your .jsx to .js conversion.

The issue/downfall with this process is that you can't lint .jsx files in the editor. But keeping a terminal window open that you can see while editing is a helpful replacement. Uing TMUX with Vim and Grunt in different panes is my preferred way to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Amey's answer is correct but also could be updated today:

Pair of **eslint** and **eslint-plugin-react** now support es6+jsx+react so **babel-eslint** is needed only if you use some specific stuff like  class properties, decorators, async/await, types.

Example **.eslintrc** configuration for react+jsx+es6 without babel-eslint:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "semi": 0
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```

You can just look at **eslint-plugin-react** instructions for further details/information.