# Tool for checking codestyle in JSX files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jscs

There are exists many beautiful code formatting tools for vanilla Javascript. For example, [JSCS](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs). Is there any tool that can validate and format reactjs templates?

I have got error like that one at this moment

```
Unexpected token < at static/view/Auth.jsx :
    34 |
    35 |  return (
    36 |      <div className="auth-page"></div>
```

Comment: jshint ? https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1260

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248504/getting-facebooks-react-js-library-jsx-syntax-to-play-nicely-with-jslint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSCS can be used with React. You have to add flag  `--esprima=esprima-fb`
to make it compatible with jsx syntax.

If you're starting your JSCS from cmd:
`jscs path[ path[...]] --esprima=esprima-fb`

If you have a .jscrsc config file add `"esprima" : "esprima-fb"`

Comment: Cant set it in config file, get `Error: Unsupported rules: esprima`.

Comment: okey, first you need to install that package `npm i --save-dev esprima-fb`